# Return immediately in spring web flux

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I am trying to create framework which should return 201 response. When a request is made to an API then i want to send back response immediately and process the request in background.

```
Flux.fromIterable(request.getApiRequests()).log().flatMap(item -> {

        WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec apiCallSpec = WebClient.create(request.getBasePath())
                .method(item.getHttpMethod()).uri(item.getPath()).accept(MediaType.valueOf(item.getAccept()))
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(item.getContentType())).body(BodyInserters.fromObject(item.getPayload()));

        return apiCallSpec.retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }).subscribe();

    return Mono.just("Created");
```

I want the flux part to happen in the background  but as of now API waits and responds once whole flux is streamed.

Comment: that is because you are using subscribe

Comment: could you please let me know what should be done? If i don't use subscribe that piece of code won't execute.

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, I can suggest you use a different design.

Don't create a Flux in your (what I presume to be) controller above. Instead you could create an instance of a Hot Stream in your app (could be a Bean in your context) and then use that instance like this:

```
myHotStream.next(item);
```

Another component in you app can the use the same instance to subscribe to it.

Read the documentation here: http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold
And another example [here](http://www.baeldung.com/reactor-core), chapter **8. Hot Streams**

**Edit**

Just a sidenote. Usually *HTTP 201 Created* implies that an entity has been successfully created. If this *creation* happens asynchronously after you send the response, it might be better to send an *HTTP 200 OK* instead. You cannot guarantee that the *creation* was successful but you can communicate that the request has been successfully received (ex: passed validation).

Comment: It is 202 actually. I am looking into hot stream thanks