# Running a Mono in background while returning a response when using Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

This questions is related to [Return immediately in spring web flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683802/return-immediately-in-spring-web-flux) but I don't think it's the same (at least the answer there is not satisfactory for me).

I have a function returning a `Mono` that when invoked starts a long-running job. This function is invoked when a call is made to a Spring Webflux HTTP API. Here's an example:

```
@PutMapping("/{jobId}")
fun startNewJob(@PathVariable("jobId") jobId: String,
                request: ServerHttpRequest): Mono<ResponseEntity<Unit>> {
    val longRunningJob : Mono<Job> = startNewJob(jobId)
    longRunningJob.map { job ->
        val jobUri = generateJobUri(request, job.id)
        ResponseEntity.created(jobURI).build<Unit>()
    }
}
```

The problem with the code above is that "201 Created" is created *after* the long running job is completed. I want to kick-off the `longRunningJob` in the background and return "201 Created" immediately.

I could perhaps do something like this:

```
@PutMapping("/{jobId}")
fun startNewJob(@PathVariable("jobId") jobId: String,
                request: ServerHttpRequest): Mono<ResponseEntity<Unit>> {

    startNewJob(jobId)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newSingle("thread"))
        .subscribe()

    val jobUri = generateJobUri(request, job.id)
    val response = ResponseEntity.created(jobURI).build<Unit>()
    Mono.just(response)
}
```

But it doesn't seem very idiomatic to me to have to call `subscribe()` manually (e.g. intellij is complaining that I call `subscribe()` in non-blocking scope). Isn't there a better way to compose the two "streams" without using an explicit `subscribe`? If so how do I modify the `startNewJob` function above to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, using one of the `subscribe` methods is the only way to really start a job in the background with its own lifecycle (not tied to the returned publisher).

If you were to use one of the operators to combine the job publisher and the response publisher (e.g. `zip` or `merge`), then the lifecycle of the job publisher would be tied to the response publisher, which is not what you want for a background job.

One thing you might want to consider is *kicking off* the background job within the response publisher stream, rather than directly in the method body.  e.g. via `doOnSubscibe` or from an operator upstream of the response.

This would tie the start of the background job to the onSubscribe events of the response publisher, but still allow it to complete in the background.

Also note, that if you want to be able to cancel the background job (e.g. maybe during application shutdown), you'll need to save the `Disposable` returned from `subscribe` so you can later call `dispose` on it.  This might be better done from some type of BackgroundJobManager that could keep track of all the jobs running.

Comment: are any of the threads getting blocked in the first option when it returns 201 after long running job is completed?

Comment: If your job calls blocking code, then that blocking code will block a thread.  You can ensure blocking code runs on a `Scheduler` meant for blocking code (e.g. `Schedulers.boundedElastic()`) by using `.publishOn` or `.subscribeOn` appropriately.

Comment: assuming that the “long running job” is reactive end to end, the client calling the api will block waiting for response, but the threads, are they always working too during this time?

Comment: In general, yes, as long as you're not calling blocking code.  But more specifically...the operators you use to assemble your stream will determine which threads are utilized to perform work.  You have full control over which threads the stream will use. 
 See https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers.  Some operators (such as `Flux.delayElements`) will use specific schedulers by default to prevent blocking a Thread.

Answer (score -2):

```
private static final Scheduler backgroundTaskScheduler = Schedulers.newParallel("backgroundTaskScheduler", 2);
backgroundTaskScheduler.schedule(() -> doBackgroundJob());
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.